# Не определяется программно местополаженеи устройства андройд

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь при запуске карты сразу определять местоположение устройства,однако, карта открывается ,загружается ландшафт но местоположение не определяется.
В манифесте все указано и прописаны все необходимые разрешения.Ключ получен. Если  явно указать координаты любого города в onMapReady то загружается нужный нам город

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 123;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean gpsStatus;
    boolean isgpsStatus;
    List<Address> addresses;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    Double latitude, longitude;
    Double currentLatitede, currentlongitude;
    LatLng latLng;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private Button selectcordinate;


    private String country;


    private LocationManager manager;
    private String knownName;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public SharedPreferences mapsprefernce;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        CheckGpsStatus();
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        manager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        selectcordinate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectcordinate);



    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }



    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        currentLatitede = location.getLatitude();
        currentlongitude = location.getLongitude();

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.draggable(true);

        markerOptions.title("Ваше местоположение");
        markerOptions
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Creating a marker

                mMap.clear();
                currentLatitede = 0.0;
                currentlongitude = 0.0;
                MarkerOptions marker =
                        new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                                .title("Текущее местоположение");

                latitude = point.latitude;
                longitude = point.longitude;
                // Animating to the touched position
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18);
                mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                mMap.addMarker(marker);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Ошибка подключения", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[],
            int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                        grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat
                            .checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckGpsStatus() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        gpsStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (gpsStatus) {
            Log.d("GPS-IS-inable", "gps включено");
            return true;


        } else {

            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
            return false;


        }

    }


    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("ВНИМАНИЕ!").setMessage(R.string.enablegpsintenet).setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setCancelable(false).setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog,
                            @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

    private void fulladress() {
        if (CheckGpsStatus()) {
            Log.d("gpsStatus", "gpsStatus " + gpsStatus);
            Log.d("internet", "internet доступен");


            geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());


            try {
                if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                } else {
                    if (currentLatitede != null && currentlongitude != null) {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLatitede, currentlongitude, 1);

                    }

                }

                address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(
                        0);
                city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

                country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                if (address != null) {
                    resultIntent.putExtra("addresses", address);
                }
                if (city != null) {
                    resultIntent.putExtra("city", city);
                }

                if (country != null) {
                    resultIntent.putExtra("country", country);
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

                MapsActivity.this.finish();

                Log.d("coordinate",
                        "mtsto " + address + " ,\n " + city + "  ,\n " + country);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Проверьте настройки", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            View view = snack.getView();
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            snack.show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }


    public void addcordinate(View view) {

        fulladress();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу в коде, чтобы вы что-то делали, если checkSelfPermission() не возвращает PERMISSION_GRANTED. Если у вас андроид 6 и новее, попробуйте в настройках включить разрешение. Если поможет - запрашивайте в коде.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request